# Prove that: $n^2+3n^3 + 6^{lgn} is $ $\theta(n^3)$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, computational-complexity

I'm asked to prove that: 
$n^2+3n^3 + 6^{lgn} is $ $\theta(n^3)$

I know that for Big O, I need to show: $f(n) <= c*g(n)$
But I'm not sure how to show this, since it involves theta.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n) = 3n^3+n^2+6^{\log_2 n} = 3n^3+n^2+n^{\log_2 6}$ and $g(n)=n^3$.

Show both $f(n) = O(g(n))$ *and* $g(n) = O(f(n))$. This is exactly showing $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Comment: Usually in this context, $\lg =  \log_2$

Comment: This seems quite complex for a 2 line question.

Comment: @lhf  I always use $\log$ for $\log_2$ and $\ln$ for the natural log. Will make that clear.

Comment: @TEDED Well, you said you knew about $O(\cdot)$ (but were confused about $\Theta(\cdot)$). Hence I assumed no other knowledge and suggested an approach that only relies on this. I would go another way, personally: I would show that $$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 3$$ which in particular implies $f(n)=\Theta{g(n)}$ (and is a bit stronger, as it gives an asymptotic equivalent -- i.e., tight constants).

Comment: Coudn't I just take the limit of the whole thing, and divide by the highest power?

Comment: This is how you'd show the limit is 3, yes.